# Android: Specify style to particular view type within a layout

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to know is there a CSS like way to style child `View`s within a particular Layout.

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fieldGroup1"
        style="@style/field_group"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemExpiry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <!-- More TextViews !>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Another LinearLayout !>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the styles

```
<style name="field_group">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/padded_text_view</item>
</style>

<style name="padded_text_view">
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
</style>
```

However, the `TextView`s within the `LinearLayout` that has the `field_group` style, don't inherit the 5dp padding.

I know I can apply the style to every `TextView`s, but is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your style will not be applied to the childs. The explanation can be the following. Different views have the same attributes and can nest each other. Thus, if parent and child view has the same parameter that is overrode in style then, according to your logic, it will be applied to the parent and to the child. If you want for child other value you should create another style. It seems to be very consuming.

I guess that you can solve your problem using themes. Themes are applied to all elements of an activity. Thus, this can help you.

Comment: I have considered using a theme, but I want to apply the styles to only some `TextView`s, and not all in the `Activity`. Can themes do this?

Comment: No, it is applied to all components of the activity.